# Move WooCommerce product tabs out of the tabs

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, tabs

I want to have the product tabs out of the tabs section and put them one down the other with no need of having the tabs functionality.

I can unset the tabs

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

     unset( $tabs['description'] );
     unset( $tabs['reviews'] );
     unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );

   return $tabs;
}
```

but I dont know how to reset them in columns layout and not in tabs.

Thanks for any help

Comment: where to move product tab?

Comment: I want to disable tabs and have the section in the same place, but on down the other. Not in tabs

Comment: not clear please send screen ? i wait

Comment: move the tabs below the image/description area ?

Comment: @vikrantzilpe here is the screen of what I want to achieve  https://prnt.sc/ln4y8z having the info in the same place but without tabs

Comment: ok i send solution please wait

Comment: Thanks @vikrantzilpe. Do you have any progress for the solution?

Comment: please use plugin :https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-extend-tabs/          and https://teamtreehouse.com/community/woocommerce-reviews-move-out-of-tabs-and-to-bottom-of-the-product-page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86259/discussion-between-vikrant-zilpe-and-bill).

Comment: solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that `woocommerce_get_template()` was deprecated and replaced by `wc_get_template()`. I solved this by adding this to my `functions.php`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'removing_product_tabs', 2 );

function removing_product_tabs(){
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
    add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','get_product_tab_templates_displayed', 10 );
}

function get_product_tab_templates_displayed() {
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/additional-information.php' );
    comments_template();
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I have to work for my other tabs that are on the theme